# How to pass window variable with ActiveAdmin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Have an issue with `ActiveAdmin` and browser, need to pass window variable from `ActiveAdmin`.

Count you help me and tip how to do that, please?

Comment: pass what to where at when?

Comment: Create window variable from ActiveAdmin

Comment: render a partial into active admin where you set the window var with javascript